Bash AND operator (&&) causes unexpected token if used within an if statement
I have found && to cause an error in bash when used within an if-statement. I am wondering if anyone has an explanation as to why this occurs and if there is a way to only run command3 if command1 and 2 exited normally. I note that var could be either empty or not in this example.
Here is a minimal example:
#!/bin/bash

var=empty or not
command1
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
  command2 &&
fi
command3
>>> line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'


How do you expect the operator to work? It should have a LHS and RHS expression. The script will behave as you describe if you remove both '&&'s from it.

Considering you are using bash, you can do all this using Parameter Expansion. Have a look at this page: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100  You don't need if and fi

echo "var is not empty" && fi - what? How is that supposed to work?

I guess you were trying to have something like if [ -n "$var" ]; then echo "var is not empty"; else false; fi (not that I'm saying it is a good way to do it).

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command to see if you understand the use of && correctly.

Basically i am running subprograms at test1, 'var not empty', and test2, however i only want to run var not empty and test2 if all previous statements have exited without errors.

To run command3 only if command2 was successful, you use
command2 && command3

You also want to only run command2 if $var is not empty. So, command3 only runs if command2 worked, and command2 only runs if $var isn't empty. In other words, command3 runs if $var is not empty and if command2 succeeded. This will work:
#!/bin/bash

var=empty or not
command1
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
  command2 && command3
fi

The reason it failed is because && expects something on the right hand side, but you didn't give it anything. The next token was fi, not a command, so && doesn't work in that context.
Now, if you want to stop if command1 failed, you could do this:
#!/bin/bash

var=empty or not
command1 &&
  if [ -n "$var" ]; then
    command2 && command3
  fi

This way, if command1 fails, the if statement is never evaluated. You might also want to consider setting the errexit option, assuming bash, which makes the script exit if any command1 fails:
#!/bin/bash

## set the errexit option
set -e 

var=empty or not
command1
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
  command2
  command3
fi

Finally, if you want to run command3 even when $var is empty, but in the case where $var is not empty, command3 should run only if command2 succeeded, you want something like this:
#!/bin/bash

var=empty or not
command1
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
  command2 && command3
else
  command3
fi


1 Note that "any command" here means "any command not used as part of a conditional". For example, if false; then echo true; done will "fail" since false exits with a non-0 status by design, however, a script running in a shell with errexit set will not exit because of this.

@terdon, just a reminder that rather commonly, the "part of a condition" status is inherited into function calls, i.e. calling a function as part of a condition disables errexit for the whole function, so e.g. foo() { false; echo wat; }; foo && true prints wat. That may be a trap if someone later moves the logic to a function and adds a useful exit status for the whole...

The && operator runs the command on the left-hand side and only if it succeeds, then runs the right-hand side.
foo && bar is pretty much the same as if foo; then bar; fi.
If you want to run multiple commands sequentially, with the next one running only if the prior ones all succeed, the straightforward way is to just stack if statements or && operators:
if cmd1; then
    if cmd2; then
        cmd3
    fi
fi

or
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3

If you also want to exit the shell at the end, if any of the commands failed, you could stack a || operator at the end:
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 || exit 1

This works, because if one of cmd1..cmd3 fails, the remaining && skip running the following ones, and the last || picks up the falsy exit status and runs the exit. The downside is that you have no idea which command failed, and the whole structure is a bit obfuscated.

It might be more readable in the future to just be explicit about it:
cmd1 || exit 1
cmd2 || exit 1
cmd3 || exit 1

because this way, you can rather easily add error messages too:
die() {
    printf >&2 "error: %s, stop.\n" "$*"
    exit 1
}
cmd1 || die "cmd1 failed"
cmd2 || die "cmd2"
cmd3 || die "cmd3"


Would probably make sense in the future, but for the existing script I had using set -e was easier, though less readable.

@TheisJendal, yep. If and when you do use it, just remember, it does have its oddities. Just so that you know if you stumble upon a case where it doesn't work as you'd expect. See e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Just remove && at line 7.
 $ echo "test1" && if [ -n "$var" ]; then echo "var is not empty" && fi
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
✘-2 ~

versus
 $ echo "test1" && if [ -n "$var" ]; then echo "var is not empty"; fi
test1
var is not empty
✔ ~

But generally speaking, I don't see a reason in your example to keep echo "test" &&, because I barely can imagine echo wouldn't work.
If you'd like to exit on any error command in your script, I would suggest you to check set -e bash feature.
